# In Client server Communication, Base64 conversion or Byte array , which one is efficient way to pass image

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface, native

I was Passing Mat image from Android to Native jni (cpp). I was using opencv to pass Mat image from android to jni but FPS count is 3.2 it become very slow. To convert Base64 string and passing to jni is efficient way to pass? or directly Pass bitmap byte array is efficient way to pass? please justify which one is most preferable for client server communication.

Comment: Encoding to base64 increases the payload with 30%. So not a good idea. It serves nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you base64-encode your image, you'll have to decode it later (on the client). That takes time and wastes resources (what if you had to encode/decode billions of images?)

An image is binary *already*, so the fastest way would probably be to simply read (or generate) an image and send it *as it is*.

All in all, you'd better do not do thousands CPU cycles when you can do only a few.

Comment: Thank you for your response , Any idea about what exact image size for byte array to pass efficiently..